# MVC Full Screen

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, flash

I have a working MVC project.

I want to include a page which displays images from database, in FULL SCREEN MODE.

How do i go about this? Flash? SilverLight? Please direct towards some tutorials.

Thanks.
Anil

Answer (score 0):

FULL SCREEN MODE in flash is not possible with out the users permission example:

If a person was to view your webpage.You would have to have a button for the user to interact with to allow a fullscreen mode.
This is a security feature that Flash has implemented to its framework,to ensure that advertisers could not abuse this feature if it was available, And also other novice users are not familiar of how to exit the screen as they are used to using the back button on the web browser.

Im sure the above applies for most.

Answer (score 0):

> FULL SCREEN MODE

You should read [this article](http://css.dzone.com/articles/pragmatic-introduction-html5), assuming you want to implement some kind of full-screen mode. Not sure if it's different from FULL SCREEN MODE, though.

> We now have access to a method called `requestFullScreen` ... implemented in Firefox, Google Chrome and Safari. (To) make it work ... we need this code

```
var docElm = document.documentElement;
if (docElm.requestFullscreen) {
    docElm.requestFullscreen();
}
else if (docElm.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    docElm.mozRequestFullScreen();
}
else if (docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
    docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen();
}
```

Comment: Hi, the example code is not working in IE. Is there any way we can achieve the same in IE? Can we have one view with silverlight full screen functionality?